# Azure ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' (CertificateOperations)

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

We have an app service that needs to access a key vault on Azure. We have 2 subscriptions, and this is working fine in one of them. The other one is new and we're getting this error (C# code in app service):

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement.Models.ErrorResponseException:
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement.CertificateOperations.DeleteWithHttpMessagesAsync
(String resourceGroupName,
 String serviceName,
 String certificateId,
 String ifMatch,
 Dictionary`2 customHeaders,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement.CertificateOperationsExtensions.DeleteAsync
(ICertificateOperations operations,
 String resourceGroupName,
 String serviceName,
 String certificateId,
 String ifMatch,
 CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

We already compared pretty much all resources, settings, keys, permissions, access policies, managed identities, everything that we think could be causing this issue, but it is still not working. The code is the same, so it does not come from there. Must be something obvious but this error message does absolutely not tell us what the root cause is.
Anyone could point us to the setting we're missing? If this is related to the account running the app service, how/where can we know what the account is on Azure?

Comment: Is there any networking involved ? is the app working in the same subscription as the kv ?

Comment: @Thomas Same subscription. We actually had only a DEV and a PRD sub. STG environment was in DEV sub (along with DEV environment) and it was working. PRD env in PRD sub is also working. When we moved STG to its own STG sub, it stopped working. We spent the day comparing STG and PRD, both Azure and service configs, and did not find the issue.

Comment: You may have to delete the access policies and recreate them. same for the identities. Like the `resourceIds` will be different and not sure Azure handle that when you're moving resource to  new subscription. Found this article related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/move-subscription

Comment: @Thomas thank you for the link. We tried that as well (new sub is in the same tenant so we didn't do anything about that). We double-checked all ids. The only difference is that in the new sub, they assigned a system managed identity to the service. But we added all ids to the KV access policies, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, the issues were:

1. Client certificates were actually stored in APIM and not in KV.
2. Service needed API Management Service Contributor permission instead of Contributor to be able to perform operations on the certificates stored in APIM.

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

> Contributor
> -> Grants full access to manage all resources
>
> API Management Service Contributor
> -> Can manage service and the APIs